# Updating Android Studio stops emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-emulator

After updating Android Studio 4.2.2 Emulator suddenly stopped working.

Tried everything, delete and reinstall emulator even reinstalled Android Studio.
Downgrade Android Studio  again Upgrade Android Studio.
Nothing is working.
Now if I try to run Emulator it says:

> The emulator process for AVD was killed.

Comment: Android 8 is working but 9+ is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I had installed R (Api level 30) x86 for my emulator but it starts giving me problems so instead i installed R(Api Level 30)x86_64 for my emulator and fixed all .You can install x86_64 system image file and give a try

Comment: Which Operating System are you using Linux or Windows

Comment: Windows 10. Android Studio 4.2.2

Comment: Try this :Help -> Check for Updates... and chose "Update All" to update everything in the list.Then restart the Android Studio Ide

Comment: did it many times. everything is up-to-date.

Comment: Can I know how much GB Ram your windows computer has?

Comment: 16gb. 128 ssd. 40gb space available.

Comment: How much ram and internal storage you have given for your emulator (you can see that in avd manager)?

Comment: Your Emulator ram should be around 1 or 1.5 gb and internal storage should be atleast 6gb(in you emulator)

Comment: 1536 MB RAM.  4096MB internal Storage

Comment: it worked with android 8. create image with android 9 or 10 is not working.